# Check box column in table is not able to sort

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sortable

I am using [bootstrap-sortable](https://github.com/drvic10k/bootstrap-sortable) to sort a table . It is working fine for all column except check box column .

What I am expecting is when some one checked uncheck checkbox and after that when someone click on table header of the table it will sorted on the basis of checkbox which are checked.

I am also setting `data-value` of the column to `1` when someone checking checkbox . It is also not helping

```
     <table id="selectedFeesToInvoiceTable" class="sortable table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead class="table-header">
                <tr>
                    <th class="borderFix"><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckBox" style="vertical-align:-2px;margin-right:5px;" />Select all</th>
                    <th>Fee date range</th>
                    <th>Case</th>
                    <th>Transaction type</th>
                    <th class="text-right" style="padding-right:2%;">Amount</th>
                    <th class="text-right" style="padding-right:2%;border-width:2px 2px 2px 0;">Exp terms</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```