# How to persist input values in bootstrap-table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

Here is the fiddle I created for this issue https://jsfiddle.net/hcancelik/na9ovj2v/17/

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-search="true" data-sort="true" data-maintain-selected="true">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th>Stars</th>
    <th data-searchable="false">Test</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
.... rest of the code is in the fiddle...
```

When you check any of the checkboxes or type a value in the text input, they don't persist if you sort the table or search. How can I make sure they persist the latest value?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24431124/57091

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @robsch but this questin is about bootstrap-table and that one is about bootstrap-sortable

Answer (score 0):

I know this is now really old, but the current version of bootstrap table has been working fine for me with checkboxes and sorting.  They have this example:

https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#options/id-field.html